# My Java code does not retrieve anything inserted manually into the SQL database?

Tags: java, sql

My Java code works on retrieving data I inserted into the SQL database. However, if I manually put data into the SQL server then it will not be retrieved by the Java code. In other words, it does not retrieve everything from the database. Instead, it will only get things that I inserted into it from my Java code. I know this because if I do a select * from table in SQL then I retrieve more data than if I do a select * from table in the Java code. How do I fix this?

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ItemDAO {

    // database information
    private Connection connection = null;
    private String user = ""; //took out
    private String pass = ""; //took out
    private String databaseURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl";
    private ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();

    // empty constructor
    public ItemDAO() {

    }

    public int[] getConnection() throws SQLException {
        int[] rowCount = new int[3];
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"); // tries to set up driver class for oracle
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("The Driver Class for Oracle was not found" + e);
        }
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, user, pass);
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet;
            for(int i = 0; i <= 2; i++){
                String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM PURCHASES WHERE PURCHASE_TYPE = " + i;
                resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                while(resultSet.next()){
                    rowCount[i] = resultSet.getInt("total");
                }
                resultSet.close();
            }
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
             sqle.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("The connection to the database was unsucessful." + sqle);
        }
        return rowCount;
    }
```

Comment: Make sure both sessions commit.  Also be sure both sessions connect to the same database properly.

Comment: @JonArmstrong is probably right, you are inserting stuff "manually" but probably never commit it.